# Assembly IA-32: Adding/subtracting 32-bit signed values and returning a signed 64-bit

Tags: assembly, x86, att

On a IA-32 architecture how do I sum/subtract two **32-bit signed** values and store the result in a **64-bit** (EDX:EAX) while mantaining the sign?

For this 32 bit values :

```
A = 97
B = 232
C = 2147483600
D = 200
```

How do I do  C + A - D + B and return a 64 bit value in **Assembly**?

Note: the result from C + A overflows the 32-bit registry.

I tried to use the **adc** function to add the carry to the edx after adding C to A but, since its signed, it does not do what i pretend.

What i tried for C+A, but it does not keep the sign:

```
#Prologue
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp

    #Body
    movl $0, %edx
    movl $0, %ecx
    movl $0, %eax
    movb 8(%ebp), %al       #
    movsx %al, %eax         #move with sign extention to 32 bit eax
    addl 16(%ebp), %eax     #adding C + A
    adcl $0, %edx
```

I also have the same problem if C was -97 and A was -2147483600 (for negative values).

Comment: I don't quite understand your sample code.  Could you show me your whole code, including where you store `A`, and `C`?  Your basic approach seems correct.

Comment: this is updated, the A value was initially a char, given by parameter, and the transformed into a 32-bit value to add to C

Comment: If you want to do do a 64 bit addition, clearly you need to sign-extend `al` into a 64 bit value.  For example, you could do `movsbl 8(%ebp), %eax; clq` to convert `8(%esp)` into a 64 bit value in `%edx:%eax`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to expand the 32-bit signed values to 64-bit signed values before the respective calculation with [`CDQ`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CWD:CDQ:CQO.html):

```
.section .data

fmt: .string "Result: %lli\n"

.section .text
.globl main

main:
    pushl $97           # A
    pushl $232          # B
    pushl $2147483600   # C
    pushl $200          # D
    call do_it
    add $8, %esp

    push %edx
    push %eax
    push $fmt
    call printf
    add $8, %esp

    pushl $0
    call exit

do_it:
    pushl %ebp                  # Prologue
    movl %esp, %ebp

    mov 12(%ebp), %eax          # C
    cdq
    mov %edx, %edi              # X = C
    mov %eax, %esi

    mov 20(%ebp), %eax          # A
    cdq
    add %eax, %esi
    adc %edx, %edi              # X += A

    mov 8(%ebp), %eax           # D
    cdq
    sub %eax, %esi              # X -= D
    sbb %edx, %edi

    mov 16(%ebp), %eax          # B
    cdq
    add %eax, %esi
    adc %edx, %edi              # X += B

    mov %edi, %edx              # RETURN = X
    mov %esi, %eax

    leave                       # Epilogue
    ret
```

Comment: Your function clobbers ESI and EDI without saving/restoring them.  But yes, you unfortunately can't use `adc $0, %edx` for the high half unless you know the input 32-bit value is signed positive (so the high half of its sign extension to 64 bit is 0).

Comment: You can save the last 2 `mov` instructions by doing add/adc into EDX:EAX instead of the other direction, after using `mov`+`cdq` to sign-extend B into EDX:EAX.

Comment: @PeterCordes: My intention was to write as simple an example as possible for learning purposes. We can argue for a long time about whether or not to adhere to the calling conventions (the ESI/EDI thing) in assembly. I have decided to leave it out so as not to complicate the matter unnecessarily. The same with the last mov instructions: With the reverse trick the last block becomes immovable. So the OP can move the blocks and play with other combinations.